# Camera Lens app navigation is not working in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, camera, windows-phone-8

My problem is somewhat specific moreover i am working on this scenario for the first time. I am building the application in Windows Phone 8 , here my requirement is to launch the page from my application when user taps on the Listed lens apps list from the ViewFinderLaunch.

This MSDN link helped me a lot.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662936(v=vs.105).aspx

Below link too:

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Extending_the_Windows_Phone_8_Camera_App_with_Lenses

So far above tutorials helped me to complete the Camera Lens application. But one problem is stopping me to complete it 100%. When the application is running, if i put the code to navigate to the Page A.xaml, it is not navigating. Unfortunately this works perfectly fine when the my application is not running.

Code that is used to navigate to page A.xaml from ViewFinderLaunch.

```
if (uri.IsWellFormedOriginalString())
            {
                if (uri.OriginalString.Contains("ViewfinderLaunch"))
                {
                    return new Uri("/A.xaml",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                }
            }
```

Could you please anyone help me on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a week, i found the reason for the problem. In my Windows Phone app, i had enabled Application resume in the WPAppManifest.xml.

```
<Tasks>
      <DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="HomePage.xaml" ActivationPolicy="Resume" />
    </Tasks>
```

When ActivationPolicy is Resume, it created this problem. So I just resolved this problem by changing this ActivationPolicy into Replace.